# Would cPanel or Plesk slow down my site/server?

Tags: performance, centos6

My senior sysadmin told me that if I install cPanel or Plesk (or other panel) on a client's machine as it would slow down the server/site (WordPress on LAMP).

This doesn't seem to make logical or intuitive sense to me. The senior is a bit too tight-winded and does not encourage questions - I am supposed to take his word as a commandment from God. So, anyway, I have been Googling for actual info on this, but haven't found anything.

Is there any truth to the assertion that a panel slows down the server/site?

(I know there are numerous other disadvantages of using panels, so please focus your answers just on this single issue of performance/speed)

Answer (score 2):

Adding a service always has a performance cost.

The question is will adding the service benefit more than the additional overhead. The main concern is not really performance, it's that the increased complexity always has a management penalty. The more stuff on a box the more likely it is to go down/have issues and the longer it will take to determine what they are.

If it's a VM or your environment is otherwise sensitive to workloads I'd say the increase in overhead would not be insignificant but really it depends on the environment. Is the server under stress now? Are the network, memory, compute or storage subsystems all running with excess capacity during peak load?

Do you have a way to objectively determine if the system is working properly and what, if any, the performance impact will be after making the proposed changes?

Comment: Thanks! The statement was made as a cardinal rule. That said, the context in which I asked was for a client's VPS as the client asked for it. We don't know loads etc as just setting the new server up.

Comment: Understood, a lot of senior admins (myself included) expect people to look stuff up, not realizing that there is a lot of context/realm info that is a lot easier to just give right then.